# Pie Chart with d34raphael

Tags: svg, raphael, d3.js, vml

I need to draw a pie chart that's works in IE 8, so I'm using d34raphael.

currently this is my code, which is modified from a d3 pie chart example https://raw.github.com/mbostock/d3/master/examples/pie/pie.html

```
var width = 300,
    height = 300,
outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
innerRadius = outerRadius * .6,
data = d3.range(10).map(Math.random),
color = d3.scale.category20(),
donut = d3.layout.pie(),
arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius);

// #chart is a div
var paper = new Raphael($('#chart')[0], width, height);
var svg = d3.raphael(paper);

 paper.setStart();

 var vis = svg.selectAll('rect')
.data([data])
.enter().append('rect')
   .attr('x', 0)
   .attr('y', 0)
   .attr('width', width)
   .attr('height', height);

svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(donut)
.enter().append('path')
   .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return color(i); })
   .attr('d', arc)
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + outerRadius + ',' + outerRadius + ')');

paper.setFinish().transform(['t', 0, 0]);
```

it crashes when I pass donut into the data function, the bind function inside d3's data function has a `group` argument. after stepping through the data function, I found that `group` was undefined. (for me, it crashes on d3.v2.js:4997 `bind(group = this[i], value.call(group, group.parentNode.__data__, i));`, it tries to reference `parentNode` on the undefined `group`) I think this may be related to raphael not supporting the g tag. any Ideas on how i can use the d3 pie layout with d34raphael? Thanks